# Soundex SQL Server CE

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

I am trying to run this query `SELECT * FROM Student WHERE DIFFERENCE(FirstName,'Joe')>=2`. I am using SQL Server CE database. I a `The function is not recognized by SQL Server Compact Edition.` error every time. How do I implement a Soundex search in SQL Server CE and VB.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I think that the closest you will come to anything like soundex is the Like function.  SQL Server CE only has a very limited set of functionality and is only really for CRUD applications.  If you absolutely need to have soundex then I would suggest using SQL Server Express instead.

Another option would be Lucene.net.  [Have a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6383463/29467)

[Available functions in SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174077%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Soundex may not work in Sql Compact, please try in Sql Server 2008 Express or any other version you have. Database should be in `.mdf' file